# Getting the Url that the user tried to access

Tags: 2013, development, application-pages, sharepoint-on-prem

I am trying to develop a Custom Access Denied Page.
Trying to display some information on the page. User's information, The site they came from, and the document/page they tried to access.

I can get the user's information from Clientcontext and the site they came from via Httpcontext.Request.UrlReferrer but I don't know how to get the url of the document/page they clicked before hitting the access denied page.
Is there a way to get this?

Many thanks,

Ova

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've posted it as an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get this by the `Source` parameter from the access denied page's url. I'm using something like this:

```
current.Request.QueryString["Source"]
```